# How in general does one find the Latex \fontfamily name for "non-usual" fonts

Tags: fonts, fontfamily

Here are for example are two that I have used without problem in XeTex (there are many more that I use), but I want to use them with Latex.

I know exactly where they are on my computer, but no information is available as to the
name to use with \fontfamily{*}

I tried to emulate:
\fontfamily{Adobe Times}   (which works),

None of the combinations of spaces, upper and lower case letters worked for the following two, and I have searched for answers here and elsewhere, but have not found a solution

ex. 1 Linux Libertine (https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/)

ex. 2 SBL Hebrew (https://www.sbl-site.org/educational/BiblicalFonts_SBLHebrew.aspx)

Comment: for libertine check the various support packages https://www.ctan.org/search?phrase=libertine. I doubt that there is latex support for SBL hebrew somewhere.

Comment: `pdflatex` is not set up to use TTF or OTF fonts, which are the font formats that most fonts on your computer are. Such fonts need to be converted to other formats to be used with `pdflatex`. But why do you need to use it at all? It's much easier to just use `xelatex` (or even better, `lualatex`) and then no conversion of fonts is needed. What prevents you from doing this?

Comment: latex can not use opentype. If you convert an opentype font to multiple tex fonts of at most 256 characters, you can choose the font names and the latex support such as a latex font family name.